# Android: crashed when EditText Material is empty

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Iam trying to put the code here but the site keep giving me error
So here is it

https://github.com/C9nc/Empty-EditText/blob/main/EditTextCheck

Comment: Welcome to SO . Please do not add link your code base add problematic code block with question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialised the buttons and edittexts even before you have called the content view !
Initialisation should be done after `setContentView();`

Comment: i initialised  them after setContentView yet still same the app crashes on startup

Comment: You are getting the edit Text string after the button click,so it will crash if you dont enter any values in the edit text, use TRY , Catch inside the button click